# Basic set notation - has this textbook made a mistake?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

An answer to one question claims that if it is true that
$B=\{a,b\}, G=\{\{a,b\}, \{c,2\}\}$, then it is also true that
$\{B\}\subseteq G $

But wouldn't $\{B\}=\{\{a,b\}\}$ and there is no $\{\{a,b\}\}$ in $G$.

Why does it say $\{B\}$ is a subset of $G$?  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Note that since $B=\{a,b\}$, anywhere you see $\{a,b\}$, you could instead write $B$, as in the first element of $G$.

Comment: Right, but B /= {B}, correct?  So if G={B, {c,2}} that's not the same as saying G={{B}, {c,2}}?

Comment: Also, note the key difference between _subset_ and _member_.  To pull one level of indirection out, if $S=\{a,b,c\}$ then we have $a\in S$, but $\{a\}\not\in S$; on the other hand, $a\not\subseteq S$ but $\{a\}\subseteq S$.

Comment: Indeed, Asaf's answer should make this clear for you.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thanks - yeah that helps it seems pretty obvious now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that $X\subseteq Y$ if and only if for every $x\in X$, $x\in Y$.

The only element of $\{B\}$ is $B$. Since $B\in G$ this means that indeed $\{\{a,b\}\}=\{B\}\subseteq G$.

Comment: Ahh... I think it see so where it says G={{a*b*}...}, *b* denotes all the members of B, and all the members of B are equal to B so G={{a,b}...} could have been written G={{A,B}...}?

Comment: Hal, I think you're confusing set membership $\in$ with set inclusion $\subseteq$. The argument in your post would be correct if it had asked if $\{B\} \in G$.

Comment: @Hal: I'm not sure. I don't understand what you mean by $G=\{\{a*b*\}\ldots\}\}$.

Comment: Thank you - I see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The book is right

The set {B} contains the element B, namely {a,b}. G contains {a,b} and additionally the element
{c,2}, so {B} is a subset of G.

Note that an element of a set can itself be a set.